# Switch / Checkout from Git Synchronization dialog

Tags: tortoisegit

I need to do a lot of switching between branches from a remote repository to inspect code, perform code reviews, contribute to other developers' work and such. I'm not a command line fan so I use TortoiseGit almost exclusively. I also prefer TG over Git clients in various IDEs because I find it really shines when you run into more complex operations like non-trivial three-way merges.

I noticed I find myself clicking A LOT, though. To switch to another branch consists of: Revert or stash any current local changes, fetch (to get the latest remote branches), switch/checkout. So I started looking into the "Git Synchronization" dialog, hoping that I could perform all those operations from within one dialog with a few less clicks, dialogs and OKs.

However, I simply cannot find the *switch* (or *checkout*) functionality in that dialog. Is that simply missing, or is there some other Git operation or combination of operations that accomplishes the same?

[image: Git Synchronization dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick solution

You can simply select a different branch from *Local Branch* dropdown in *Git Sync* dialog. When you subsequently invoke *Pull*, TortoiseGit will force the checkout automatically:

[image]

For other operations (*Fetch*, *Push*) switching to a branch is not necessary.  However be cautious with the *Commit* and *Show log* buttons as they will always apply to the current branch (not the branch selected in *Local Branch* dropdown) and no checkout will be  forced.

### Solution using Switch/Checkout dialog

If you need to use full *Switch/Checkout dialog* TortoiseGit dialog, you can use *Browse references* dialog which you can invoke from *Git Sync* dialog by clicking on the ellipsis button next to the *Local Branch* dropdown.

[image: Git Sync dialog - invoke Browse references dialog]

In the *Browse references* dialog there is a list of available branches. You should right click the desired branch you want to checkout and select *Switch/Checkout to this* from context menu. *Switch/Checkout* dialog will pop up. After completing the checkout, return to the *Browse references* dialog where the desired branch is selected and click *OK*. Now the desired branch is checked out and also selected as a *Local Branch* in *Git Sync* dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the following: Someone else pushed a new branch to the remote repo. I used "fetch" (same dropdown as "pull") and saw the new branch show up. However, it is not available under the "Local Branch" dropdown or the local "ellipsis" dialog because I never checked it out in the first place. To switch to new branch locally, I had to open the Remote Branch dialog, right-click and checkout new branch from there. Local Branch dropdown did not update, had to open up dialog and find and select local branch there. A lot more steps than doing it without the Sync dialog :-(

Comment: @Christoph After creating new local branch you can just go back to *Git Sync* dialog and press F5. The new local branch should then appear in Local Branch dropdown. :-)